# bundle install wrong ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I'm using RVM

```
 > rvm list
 rvm rubies

  ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ]
* ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Current Ruby version is 2.3.1 (I already added `ruby "2.3.1"` into Gemfile)

```
> ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

Bundle install

```
> bundle install --deployment
> ls ./vendor/bundle/ruby/
2.3.0
```

Why's my Ruby version 2.3.1 but bundle install result is 2.3.0? Could you guys please help me?

Comment: You might try changing `ruby-2.3.1` as  current and default version

Comment: Thanks @DeepakMahakale! But, i got same result (2.3.0 in ./vendor/bundle/ruby/).

Comment: I think you have written ruby '2.3.0' in your gemfile

Comment: I'm sure that `ruby "2.3.1"` in my Gemfile. More info, after i removed directory `.bundle` then `bundle install` without `--deployment`. It is works (use correct ruby2.3.1 in devlopment mode).

Answer (score 0):

you may try changing `2.3.1` to default

```
rvm use 2.3.1 --default
```

you can also add `.ruby-version` file in root folder of your project repository. This will make sure whenever you enter the folder it will change ruby version to **`2.3.1`**

```
#.ruby-version
2.3.1
```

Comment: I tried: `rvm --default use ruby-2.3.1` and my .ruby-version: `2.3.1`. But nothing changes.